# Google Maps API V3 - over_query_limit GeoCoderStatus confusion

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Am using this in Google Maps API 3

Basically I am adding about 150 markers to a map.  I use GeoCoding once to get lat and long in order to centre the map on a specific location but that is the ***only*** time I use GeoCoding.  However, GeoCoding returns results asychronously so I wait for results to be returned by placing the rest of the code in the GeoCode callback function (see code below).  This was all working fine until today when we started to get a blank map returned.

On investigating, I realised that the GeocoderStatus was returning **over_query_limit** and, due to the if statement, it was bypassing the rest of the code.

Upon further investigation we find out that there is a limit of 2500 GeoCode requests per day.  However, I can't really see that this particular website could have reached this limit as we are only calling GeoCode once per map request... unless of course there is something I am not understanding about our code below... is the fact that we wrap everythign in the GeoCode callback mean that we are somehow calling GeoCode more than once?

Anyway this code results in the **over_query_limit** GeoCodeStatus error sometimes and returns a blank map

```
function initialize() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapCentre = "Blackpool, United Kingdom";

    // Get lat long for city that we use to center the map within the container.
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': mapCentre }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var mapCentreLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lb, results[0].geometry.location.mb);
            // This function creates the marker - it does not use GeoCoder to look up an address as we supply the lat and long directly in our JSON
            buildMap(mapCentreLatlng);
        }
    });
}
```

And this code is fine - it no longer calls GeoCode

```
function initialize() {
   var mapCentreLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.8142, -3.0503);
   buildMap(mapCentreLatlng);
}
```

We have everything working now, but just wondering if anybody can explain?

Comment: Is your site hosted on a shared server or something like rackspace?  Perhaps another site on your server is now using up the quota.  Do you have a key to the API include? If not, adding one may give you your own quota, but this should be based on the client, not the server.  Are you running on a network with a proxy server?

Comment: Runs on our own server which runs a number of sites (all under our control). None of the other sites on the same IP have a google map.

Comment: This is a client geocoder issue.  Should only have to do with the clients (browsers) looking at the map.

Comment: so if somebody hit reload on our map page 2500 times would that cause this issue.  If they did do this surely we woudl see this in the analytics?  The first code sample above, is it clean?  Is there any possibility that geocode could be called more than once because of our buildMap function being called in the geocode callback? We definitely do not explicitly call in buildMap.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Limit of 2500 GeoCode requests in the last 24 hours from the same IP Address!
But I have found that there are sometimes less.

Comment: I know this and it seems to point to this being exceeded but I honestly dont see how.

Comment: So you have to wait for 24 hours and then you could try again. Build in a request Counter to figure out how often you start the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending request too fast you will also get this result. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits).

Comment: Based on his question, there is one geocode operation on page load.  That _should_ work.